# Get Month value from DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server Management Studio. Would like to pull the month only from the column. Have attempted the following:

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```
,Convert (CHAR, e.TERM_DATE, 110) AS [Due Date]
            ,PAT_CASE.OLD_CASE_ID AS [Case Number]
            ,CASE
                       WHEN e.TERM_DATE = 'MM-DD-YYYY' 
                       THEN DateName(MONTH, GETDATE())    
                       ELSE e.TERM_DATE 
                       END AS [MONTH]
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**ATTEMPT 2:**

```
,Convert (CHAR, e.TERM_DATE, 110) AS [Due Date]
            ,PAT_CASE.OLD_CASE_ID AS [Case Number]
            ,CASE
                       WHEN e.TERM_DATE = 'MM-DD-YYYY' 
                       THEN DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @MonthNumber , -1 ))    
                       ELSE e.TERM_DATE 
                       END AS [MONTH]
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MonthNumber".
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

**ATTEMPT 3:**

```
,Convert (CHAR, e.TERM_DATE, 110) AS [Due Date]
            ,PAT_CASE.OLD_CASE_ID AS [Case Number]
            ,CASE
                       WHEN e.TERM_DATE = 'MM-DD-YYYY' 
                       THEN SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (@intMonth * 4) - 3, 3)   
                       ELSE e.TERM_DATE 
                       END AS [MONTH]
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@intMonth".
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: Assuming that `TERM_DATE` is indeed at datetime column, have you tried the most obvious: `MONTH(TERM_DATE)` if it is the month number you want?

Comment: Yes and receive the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CAST` and the fact that `WHEN e.TERM_DATE = 'MM-DD-YYYY'` errors in the first example implies that `e.TERM_DATE` is a `DATETIME` so:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, e.TERM_DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was successful.